# React+redux, array of components. Ways to re-render only changed component from this array?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For example on page i have many components, many arrays of components.
If i dispatch some actions, the whole page with all this array of components is rerendered. 
But I dont need to rerender not changed items/ components on page. 
I want only changed component to be rerendered. I know there is shouldComponentUpdate() . But writing logic with shouldComponentUpdate in every component its not so cool. Maybe there is some libraries for this , or maybe some alternitve ways? I have heard about `reactjs/reselect`, is it right thing for such issues, or if i misunderstood, please tell which issues reselect stands for? And what with cases when then functional components are used?

Maybe there is some another libs for optimizing perfomance and controll which components to allow rebuilding?

I also found https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized  . Do these two libs for same purpose? What is difference ? Which to choose?

And one simple question, assume i am fetching data, it is adding to array.
How can i render only added items, but not the whole array each time the new item fetched?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.
I advise you to look into reselect.
Reselect allows you to memoize your data and select only the portions of your store that are being used in certain parts of your application.
Using selectors, the library will cause your DOM to rerender if your selected parts of the store are changed; however, will not even if parts of your store are changed but not connected to needed data.

Comment: I also have found https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized   Do those make the same thing  for same issue? What is differance?

Comment: I haven't messed around with react-virtualized nor react-infinite, but from my search, it seems that they are libraries for extremely specific use cases. Reselect is a "selector" library mainly for the Redux store. Meaning you can select certain parts of your data to be memoized. Don't quote me on this, but react-virtualized looks to be just a specialized library for rendering certain parts visual components virtually until needed.

Comment: How Redux works is by connecting your store (think of it as a big data object) to your app through your components. However, whenever the store changes, Reactjs reupdates your app which means unnecessary parts of your app gets rerendered due to updates completely unrelated to the change in your data. Reselect is used to battle this by "memoizing" your data (store).

Answer (score 0):

Reselect his an awesome library and this is what you need. The only downside would be if you use the selector in many components. You gonna need to have an instance of each selector to make it private. Can be done easy by making a function makeMapStateToProps like they show here https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#sharing-selectors-with-props-across-multiple-components . But I don't like making that for every selector I gonna need. So I find this library who is an extends of this last one https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect . This one do the same selectors but you can use some key for caching.

Comment: What about react-virtualized  and react-infinite?